# How to put filter in the logcat section on Android Studio 1.1.0?

Tags: android, filter, android-studio, logcat, android-logcat

I know how to do the actual logcat filtering but I can't find the icon for it. This is a view of the Logcat demonstration that I am following. [image]

The part on the top right (Log level, search box and the dropdown box) are missing on my logcat..

By the way I'm using Android Studio 1.1.0 on windows 7 64bit.

This is what it looks like on my computer[image]

Answer (score 1):

See eclipse style logcat with more functionality at:

> Tools --> Android --> Android device monitor

I hope this helps.

p.s. ADM will close if you are in debugging mode

Answer (score 0):

Things are little different on AS, but what you need is right there on the first picture check edit filter configuration on the drop down. you will see what you are looking for.